# Connect o google spreadsheet from .NET and Python

Tags: c#, python, google-sheets-api

Trying to get Google spreadsheet table content by using C# client and Python.

C# client works fine while python returns error:

```
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 404 when requesting https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/IAD2okAWZD7anbt5L4ybgD2dxHBGmsY6IkNIWHBQkBM/values/new%20first%20sheet%21A1?alt=json returned "Requested entity was not found.">
```

If I open link in error in browser I see error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "The request is missing a valid API key.",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}
```

What might be wrong in Python client?

C# client:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string ApplicationName = "aaa";
            UserCredential credential;

            using (var stream =new FileStream("credentials.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                string credPath = "token.json";
                credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                    GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                    Scopes,
                    "user",
                    CancellationToken.None,
                    new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
                Console.WriteLine("Credential file saved to: " + credPath);
            }

            // Create Google Sheets API service.
            var service = new SheetsService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
            });


            String range = "new first sheet!A2:E";//mano

            SpreadsheetsResource.ValuesResource.GetRequest request =service.Spreadsheets.Values.Get(spreadsheetId, range);


            // https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BxiMVs0XRA5nFMdKvBdBZjgmUUqptlbs74OgvE2upms/edit
            ValueRange response = request.Execute();
            IList<IList<Object>> values = response.Values;
            if (values != null && values.Count > 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Name, Major");
                foreach (var row in values)
                {
                    // Print columns A and E, which correspond to indices 0 and 4.
                    if (row.Count==1 ) Console.WriteLine("{0}", row[0]);
                    else
                        Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", row[0], row[1]);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No data found.");
            }
            Console.Read();
        }
```

Python client:

```
class SS:
    store = file.Storage('token.json')
    try:
        creds = store.get()
    except Exception as e:
        print(traceback.format_exc())

    if not creds or creds.invalid:
            flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets('credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = tools.run_flow(flow, store)
    service = build('sheets', 'v4', http=creds.authorize(Http()))
    # Call the Sheets API
    SPREADSHEET_ID = 'IAD2okAWZD7anbt5L4ybgD2dxHBGmsY6IkNIWHBQkBM'  #my
    RANGE_NAME = 'new first sheet!A1'  #my



    def __init__(self):
        print("Constructing")


    def get(self):
        print("starting get")


        result = self.service.spreadsheets().values().get(  spreadsheetId=self.SPREADSHEET_ID, range=self.RANGE_NAME).execute()
        values = result.get('values', [])

        if not values:
            print('No data found.')
        else:
            print('Name, Major:')
            for row in values:
                # Print columns A and E, which correspond to indices 0 and 4.
                print('%s, %s' % (row[0], row[4]))
```

Comment: `SCOPES` variable defined in outer scope, right?

Comment: Is your `spreadsheetId` correct? The ID in Python is different than the url shown in your C#...